# How to break content editor and append it on next page

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]I want to append current content-editor to next page when current page get completed

Here is my fiddle [Check](https://fiddle.jshell.net/niks2060/y9moh1wr/)

Any help will be appreciable

### Description

Actually what I am doing is I have created a text editor in which I have added header footer and a content-editor but now I want to add a new page with same header and footer but want to append my current page content-editor

```js
   var margin;
        var pageSize;
        var headerHeight;
        var footerHeight;
        var marginTopBottom;
        var marginLeftRight;
        var marginArray;
        var reportHeight;
        var reportWidth;

        $(function () {
            GetPage();
            jQuery("#btnGetSize").on('click', function () {
                var h = $('#Template').height();
                var w = $('#Template').width();
                var h1 = $('#ReportPage').height();
                var w1 = $('#ReportPage').width();
                alert("Template :   h=" + (parseFloat(h) / 3.76) + " w=" + (parseFloat(w) / 3.76) + "    ReportPage :   h1=" + (parseFloat(h1) / 3.76) + " w1=" + (parseFloat(w1) / 3.76) + "");
            });

            jQuery("#ddlSize").change(function () {
                GetPage();
            });

            jQuery("#ddlMargin").change(function () {
                GetPage();
            });


            $("#btnPrint1").on('click', function () {
                var divContents = $("#ReportPage").html();

                var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=1000px,width=1000px');
                printWindow.document.write('<html><head>');
                printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
                printWindow.document.write(divContents);
                printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');

                printWindow.document.close();
                printWindow.print();
            });
            //   -------------------------
            $("#btnPrint").on('click', function () {
                $('#main').addClass("page").css("display", "none");
                $('#main').addClass("print page ")
                var content_height = $('#TemplateSubPage').height();
                var page = 1;
                function buildReport() {

                    if ($('#TemplateSubPage').contents().length > 0) {

                        $page = $("#TemplatePage").clone();
                        $page.find(".subpage").empty();
                        $page.find(".footer span").append(page);
                        $("#ReportPage").append($page);
                        $('.subpage').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        $("#TemplateSubPage").prop('disabled', true);
                        page++;

                        $('#TemplateSubPage').columnize({
                            columns: 1,
                            target: ".page:last .subpage",
                            overflow: {
                                height: content_height,
                                id: "#TemplateSubPage",
                                doneFunc: function () {
                                    console.log("done with page");
                                    buildReport();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                setTimeout(buildReport, 1000);
            });

        });

        //=------------------------


        function GetPage() {

            pageSize = $('#ddlSize option:selected').text();
            margin = $('#ddlMargin option:selected').text();
            headerHeight = $('.header').height();
            footerHeight = $('.footer').height();
            marginArray = new Array();
            marginArray = GetMargins();
            marginTopBottom = parseFloat(marginArray[0]) + parseFloat(marginArray[2]) + (parseFloat(headerHeight) / 3.7) + (parseFloat(footerHeight) / 3.7);
            marginLeftRight = parseFloat(marginArray[1]) + parseFloat(marginArray[3]);

            if (pageSize == "--Select--") {
                //$("#TemplatePage .divOuter").css("width", "210mm").css("height", "290mm");
                $(".page").css("width", "210mm").css("min-height", "290mm");
                $(".subpage").css("height", 277 + "mm").css("max-height", 290 + "mm").css("width", 187 + "mm");

                // $("div .subpage").css("height", (290) + "mm").css("max-height", (290) + "mm").css("width", (210) + "mm");

            }
            else if (pageSize == "A0") {

                $(" .page").css("width", "841mm").css("min-height", "1175mm"); /*page margins top right bottom  left  */
                $(".subpage").css("height", 1155 + "mm").css("max-height", 1175 + "mm").css("width", 820 + "mm");

                // $("div .subpage").css("height", (1175) + "mm").css("max-height", (1175) + "mm").css("width", (841) + "mm");

            }
            else if (pageSize == "A1") {
                $(".page").css("width", "594mm").css("min-height", "830mm");
                $(".subpage").css("height", 810 + "mm").css("max-height", 830 + "mm").css("width", 574 + "mm");

                //$("div .subpage").css("height", (830) + "mm").css("max-height", (830) + "mm").css("width", (594) + "mm");

            }
            else if (pageSize == "A2") {
                $(".page").css("width", "420mm").css("min-height", "585mm");
                $(".subpage").css("height", 565 + "mm").css("max-height", 585 + "mm").css("width", 400 + "mm");

                // $("div .subpage").css("height", (585) + "mm").css("max-height", (585 ) + "mm").css("width", (420 - marginLeftRight) + "mm");

            }
            else if (pageSize == "A3") {
                $("div .page").css("width", "297mm").css("min-height", "413mm");
                //  $("div .subpage").css("height", (413 - marginTopBottom) + "mm").css("max-height", (413 - marginTopBottom) + "mm").css("width", (297 - marginLeftRight) + "mm");

            }
            else if (pageSize == "A4") {
                //   $("#TemplatePage .divOuter").css("width", "210mm").css("height", "290mm");
                $(".page").css("width", "210mm").css("min-height", "297mm");
                $(".subpage").css("height", 277 + "mm").css("max-height", 297 + "mm").css("width", 187 + "mm");

                // $("div .subpage").css("height", (290 - marginTopBottom) + "mm").css("max-height", (290 - marginTopBottom) + "mm").css("width", (210 - marginLeftRight) + "mm");

            }
            else if (pageSize == "A4 LandScape") {
                // $("#TemplatePage .divOuter").css("width", "297mm").css("height", "200mm");

                $(".page").css("width", "297mm").css("min-height", "200mm");
                $(".subpage").css("height", 180 + "mm").css("max-height", 200 + "mm").css("width", 277 + "mm");

                // $("div .subpage").css("height", (200 - marginTopBottom) + "mm").css("max-height", (200 - marginTopBottom) + "mm").css("width", (299 - marginLeftRight) + "mm");
            }
            else if (pageSize == "A5") {
                $(".page").css("width", "148mm").css("min-height", "200mm");
                $(".subpage").css("height", 180 + "mm").css("max-height", 200 + "mm").css("width", 126 + "mm");

            }
            else if (pageSize == "A6") {
                $(".page").css("width", "105mm").css("min-height", "142mm");
                $(".subpage").css("height", 122 + "mm").css("max-height", 142 + "mm").css("width", 83 + "mm");

                //$("div .subpage").css("height", (142 - marginTopBottom) + "mm").css("max-height", (142 - marginTopBottom) + "mm").css("width", (105 - marginLeftRight) + "mm");

            }
            else if (pageSize == "A7") {
                $(".page").css("width", "74mm").css("min-height", "101mm");
                $(".subpage").css("height", 81 + "mm").css("max-height", 101 + "mm").css("width", 51.30 + "mm");

                //  $("div .subpage").css("height", (101 - marginTopBottom) + "mm").css("max-height", (101 - marginTopBottom) + "mm").css("width", (74 - marginLeftRight) + "mm");

            }
            else if (pageSize == "A8") {
                $(".page").css("width", "52mm").css("min-height", "71mm");
                $(".subpage").css("height", 51 + "mm").css("max-height", 71 + "mm").css("width", 29.60 + "mm");

                // $("div .subpage").css("height", (71 - marginTopBottom) + "mm").css("max-height", (71 - marginTopBottom) + "mm").css("width", (52 - marginLeftRight) + "mm");

            }
        }

        function GetMargins() {

            var marginArray = new Array();
            margin = $('#ddlMargin').val();

            if (margin == 0) {
                $(".page").css("padding", "25.4mm 25.4mm 25.4mm 25.4mm");
                marginArray = ["25.4", "25.4", "25.4", "25.4"];
                return marginArray;
            }
            else if (margin == 1) {
                $(".page").css("padding", "12.7mm 12.7mm 12.7mm 12.7mm"); /*page margins top right bottom  left  */
                marginArray = ["12.7", "12.7", "12.7", "12.7"];
                return marginArray;
            }
            else if (margin == 2) {
                $(".page").css("padding", "25.4mm 25.4mm 25.4mm 25.4mm");
                marginArray = ["25.4", "25.4", "25.4", "25.4"];
                return marginArray;
            }
            else if (margin == 3) {
                $(".page").css("padding", "25.4mm 19.05mm 25.4mm 19.05mm");
                marginArray = ["25.4", "19.05", "25.4", "19.05"];
                return marginArray;
            }
            else if (margin == 4) {
                $(".page").css("padding", "25.4mm 12.7mm 25.4mm 12.7mm");
                marginArray = ["25.4", "12.7", "25.4", "12.7"];
                return marginArray;
            }
            else if (margin == 5) {
                $(".page").css("padding", "0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm");
                marginArray = ["0", "0", "0", "0"];
                return marginArray;
            }
        }
```

```css
body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font: 12pt "Tahoma";
}
.page
{
    padding: 20mm;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: white;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.subpage
{
    min-width: 10mm;
    word-break: break-all;
    cursor: text;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0px;
    padding: 1cm;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

@page
{
    margin: 0;
}
@media print
{
    /*   html, body
                {
                    width: 210mm;
                    height: 297mm;
                }
                .page
                {
                    margin: 0;
                    border: initial;
                    border-radius: initial;
                    width: initial;
                    min-height: initial;
                    box-shadow: initial;
                    background: initial;
                    page-break-after: always;
                }
            */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/285608/Miscellaneous/JS%20Libraries/columnizer/jquery.columnizer.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div id="controls">
        <div style="text-align: center; float: left; font-size: medium">
            <select id="ddlSize">
                <option id="A" value="0">--Select--</option>
                <option id="A0" value="841mm X 1189mm">A0</option>
                <option id="A1" value="594mm X 841mm">A1</option>
                <option id="A2" value="420mm X 594mm">A2</option>
                <option id="A3" value="297mm X 420mm">A3</option>
                <option id="A4" value="210mm X 297mm">A4</option>
                <option id="A4Landscape" value="297mm X 210mm">A4 LandScape</option>
                <option id="A5" value="148mm X 210mm">A5</option>
                <option id="A6" value="105mm X 148mm">A6</option>
                <option id="A7" value="74mm X 105mm">A7</option>
                <option id="A8" value="52mm X 74mm">A8</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button id="btnPrint">
            Print preview</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button id="btnPrint1">
            Print</button>
        <button id="btnGetSize">
            Get divSize</button>
        <div style="text-align: center; float: left; padding-bottom: 50px; font-size: medium;
            width: 300px">
            <select id="ddlMargin">
                <option id="No" value="0">--Select--</option>
                <option id="Narrow" value="1">0.5" 0.5" 0.5" 0.5" </option>
                <option id="Normal" value="2">1" 1" 1" 1"</option>
                <option id="Moderate" value="3">1" 0.75" 1" 0.75" </option>
                <option id="Other" value="4">1" 0.5" 1" 0.5" </option>
                <option id="NoMargin" value="5">0" 0" 0" 0"</option>
            </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--tyle="border: 1px solid black;"-->
    <div id="main">
        <div class="page" id="TemplatePage" style="page-break-after: always;">
            <div id="header">
                <center>
                    This is header</center>
                <br />
            </div>
            <div class="subpage" contenteditable="true" id="TemplateSubPage">
                <br />
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
                <br />
                <center>
                    This is Footer</center>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="ReportPage" class="divOuter">
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to add a new page with same header and footer but want to append my current page content-editor"?

Comment: I want to create a ms word style editor

Comment: header and footer with same content-editor but should have page break

Comment: You're being very vague about what it is you want to achieve, which makes it very hard to understand how to help you. What is "ms word style editor". What does it mean "header and footer with same content-editor but should have page break". What should the result look like? How is this different from what you have now. Please provide examples and/or screenshots

Comment: let me explain it.. I have created a page with header footer and a content-editor. now when I start writing in that content-editor at some instant when I reach up-to footer at same instant I want to add a new page with some header and footer but I want to append same content-editable div what I have in first page and if I have delete any word or line of text I should manage accordingly

Comment: find a way to determine the number of lines `\n` or `\r\n` in your text... If it's `>` `maxAmount` (you max value), then you insert your elements and set the focus on the "second page"

Comment: I can do that but when I am going to delete some of the text every thing get deleted...header and footer too.

Comment: @NikhilGhuse, why would it be deleted? the "second page" is new set of elements or a clone of the first ones, but never overwriting them...

Comment: word creates an object that contain the document and give access to it like an array (C# [interop...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.aspx)) ... you may want to try that approach too, so you can count the times the enter key is hit or how many of those elements `\n` are in the document...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A possible solution would be to count the number of line breaks (`\r\n` and `\n` in the case of a textArea input element), then create a new "page" element, edit the values of both old and new text areas and change the focus to the new text area. Here's a psuedo-JS event handler for this:

```
function onPageInput(event){
  //count lines in original page
  var lines = page.value.split(/\r*\n/);

  if (lines.length > linesPerPage){
    var newPage = addPage(); //returns the new page
    page.insertAfter(newPage);


    //reset original textArea value
    page.value = "";

    //populate old textarea and new textarea
    page.value = lines.slice(0, linesPerPage).join("\n");
    newPage.value = lines.slice(linesPerPage, lines.length).join("\n");

    newPage.focus();
  }
}
```

Here's a working [example implementation](http://codepen.io/OpherV/pen/NAEpoX)

Note that I used textAreas for simplification. If you want to use a ContentEditable div you will need a method to count the content lines, and break the content into two separate chunks depending on your desired line break. Some existing WYSIWYG libraries might already offer the API for line counting/splitting content without you having to work around the [pitfalls of ContentEditable](https://medium.engineering/why-contenteditable-is-terrible-122d8a40e480#.ic0xet8qo).

Of course - you will still need to handle special cases like deleting pages when the user presses backspace on an empty page, or any other behavior you want.

Comment: but still when I delete it doesn't fall back it stay in there in current div

Comment: i can do this stuff but my concern is to do delete in that div

Comment: Your original question mentions nothing of deleting. Please explain your desired behavior with detail

Comment: Actually when the page get added and if i have delete some line from first page lines from page 2 must added to end of first likewise to each pages

Comment: And if I am on second page and I have press backspace it should move to page first end and delete second page

Comment: is it possible ..??

Comment: Finally Doing all kind of R and D I have found my answer

Answer (score 2):

**[fiddle proof of concept...](https://fiddle.jshell.net/diego_carrascal/y9moh1wr/2/)**
This is more than an answer, a suggested path to try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var page = {
              newLines : 0,
              newLinesCheck : function(){
              this.newLines = $("#TemplateSubPage").val().split('\n').length - 1;
              if(this.newLines < 0){this.newLines = 0;}
            console.warn($("#TemplateSubPage").val().split('\n'));
              },
              newLine : function(){
                this.newLines++;
              }
            };

         $(document).keydown(function(k){
            //console.log(k.which);
            if(k.which == 13){ 
              page.newLine();
              console.log(page.newLines);
            }
            if(k.which == 46 || k.which == 8){// DEL, BKSPS
                page.newLinesCheck();
            }
          });
    });
```

I have to change the editable div to a textarea to allow the `\n` character to be found but in your fiddle it worked... as I say is a suggestion and doesn't work completely, but may guide you or give you ideas.

Comment: can you provide any proof of concept

Comment: [fiddle proof of concept...](https://fiddle.jshell.net/diego_carrascal/y9moh1wr/2/) if you see the console, the __intro__ (new line) is being added and when __backspace__ or __del__ keys are press, it checks if it deleted a new line character, now with that you can deside how many lines fill one page and create a new page or move the text by lines up or down. Also the editable doesn't work in all browsers and behaviour could change. My example uses `textarea`. It's meant to show you my suggestion, not to be part of your app.

Comment: @NikhilGhuse MS Word allow you to access the document content as an array of characters, you could do the same and count how many `\n` got the text, each page should have a certain amount of them, also check after each `\n` the maximum characters your line will hold, so you can insert in the text a line break (you could make it better by inserting it before the last word of that line). Then if the number of `\n` is greater than the maximum of the page, insert a full line that allow you to know that is a page break. after you read your array and put its content in a page until page break...

Comment: @NikhilGhuse of course this are just my ideas of how I would attack the problem, you may have better or find them ilogic... each one programs from experience and in a different way... I can't tell you more, I have to go back to work (break is over) Good luck.